# Does casting one generic (value) type to another with dynamic involve boxing/unboxing?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, type-inference, boxing

Given:

```
internal abstract class Animal { }
internal class Dog : Animal { }
```

I'm trying to write a generic method that can be used to cast *or* convert from one type to another, so:

```
static TOutput ConvertOrCast<TInput, TOutput>(TInput toConvert)
{
    if (toConvert is TOutput) return (TOutput)(dynamic)toConvert;
    return (TOutput)Convert.ChangeType(toConvert, typeof(TOutput));
}
```

On the first line, I need to first cast to either `(object)` or `(dynamic)` to avoid the compiler error "Cannot convert type 'TInput' to 'TOutput'".

I understand, e.g. from [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95bd301e-0044-478d-b963-8486aeff344b/dynamic-boxing-and-value-types?forum=csharplanguage), that using `dynamic` usually involves boxing/unboxing for value types, but is that happening in this case?  I'm hoping the compiler is smart enough to recognize that the input type is already the same as as the output type, because then why not just use `object` instead of `dynamic`?

Comment: Falling back to the (dynamic) cast because the type parameters are not constrained well enough is an extremely ugly hack.  The runtime cost is far higher than a boxing conversion, the DLR uses reflection under the hood to ensure the cast is safe.  Even though you already checked it is safe, the DLR doesn't know you did.  If you can't constrain it well enough then it probably shouldn't be generic.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks.  My goal is to make a generic extension method to cast if possible or, failing that, convert if possible.  Thus, the constraints would limit the usability of such a method.

Comment: @rory.ap It simply means having two methods, one for value types and one for reference types.  There's no loss of generality.  But even if you insist on using a single method, you appear to greatly overestimate the performance cost of a boxing operation, and greatly underestimate the costs of dynamic typing.  The former is *very* cheap, the latter is many orders of magnitude more expensive in time and memory used.

Comment: @Servy -- Thanks.  I've never found occasion to use `dynamic` and was just curious because I discovered it satisfies the compiler like `object` does in the above casting scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no boxing if no value types are involved.

On the other hand, you don't gain anything with the `(TOutput)(dynamic)toConvert` cast instead of `(TOutput)(object)toConvert`. It is just even worse actually.

But in C# 7.1 and above you can just avoid those multiple casts by using pattern matching:

```
if (toConvert is TOutput output) return output;
```

Comment: Even before C#7 you could have done `TOutput outVal = toConvert as TOutput` and tested for null.

Comment: @Jamiec: The `as` cast works only if you use the `class` constraint for `TOutput`.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg so would using the pattern matching involve boxing/unboxing with value types "under the hood"?

Comment: @rory.ap: Only if `TInput` and `TOutput` are different types. But considering value types cannot be derived from each other, in this case `TOutput` is necessarily a reference type (eg `int` to `IConvertible`), in which case boxing is a must.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg It's not for value types deriving from one another, it's if `TInput` is the same type as `TOutput`, e.g. `int` and `int`.

Comment: @rory.ap: There is no boxing in that case. Btw. boxing is not _that_ bad, at least it has much less cost than dynamic typing.

Comment: You do lose something be not casting to dynamic before TOutput - any implicit/explicit operators defined for the input type will not be considered.